# Using Auto Layout in UITableView, Why is there so much extra space around?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, autolayout

My environment is XCode 6.3, Using the auto layout with UITableView, I always got the extra space between top Navigation and UITableView. have some idea can reduce it ? thank you.

[image]

Comment: Try in your viewcontroller setting automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to no `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

Comment: @BooRanger Or in swift : self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added **Vertical Spacing** for your TableView.

1. Click on your tableView
2. Editor > Pin > Top Space to Superview
3. Click on Attribute Inspector
4. Set constant to 0.

---

For your **Button** to show, remove all the constraints from your button and do the following:

1. Select your button
2. Editor > Pin > Leading Space to SuperView
3. Select your button
4. Editor > Pin > Top Space to SuperView
5. Select your button
6. Editor > Pin > Height
7. Select your button
8. Editor > Pin > Width

Comment: If you are having counter question then kindly write it in comment or update the question or ask another question. Also let me know if the above solution worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase your tableview height to 600 and make sure that you set the constraints according to it. It will solve your problem!